# Is it safe to set double to int without casting?

Tags: c

Simple question. In my code I set a double to an integer, like so:

```
int square_root = sqrt(sum);
```

Do I need to explicitly cast this?

Without casting, I seem to get the result I desired, i.e. `floor(sqrt(x))`

```
sqrt(4200) = 64
sqrt(42) = 6
```

Comment: If this isn't performance critical code, then since you want the floor, why not just call `floor` and cast that to an integer, to be explicit about what you are doing?  If this is performance critical code, then I understand why you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: No, teaching myself c with project euler and couldn't find an answer to this simple q anywhere so decided to ask here :) Ie. not critical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 int square_root = sqrt(sum);
```

is equivalent in C to:

```
int square_root = (int) sqrt(sum);
```

Now be aware that if the integral part of a `double` is not representable in an `int` the behavior is undefined (in both cases).

Comment: Ehm, how could the integral part of a double not be representable as an int. Is it because the value range is too large?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat for example `int a = (double) INT_MAX + 1.0;` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Functionally there is no difference, but an explicit cast will draw the reader's attention to the fact that there is truncation going on.

Comment: So casting is truncating, that is flooring?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat. By truncating I mean flooring, yes. In both cases you have that, it's just that in case of an explicit case you're minimizing the risk that the reader might accidentally think that there is no truncation involved

Answer (score 2):

If the square root of your number is an integer, it doesn't affect. but if it's a real number (for example square root of 10) you'll get a truncated integer which may be inconvenient for your program.